# What architectural pattern or style will be used for the system that is the combination of web portal and android app?

Tags: architecture

i know most of the times android use MVC pattern but i want to know what will be pattern or style when we are developing a system that has web portal for backend management and an android app for the direct users.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous architectural solutions/patterns/styles. Which one to choose  depends on your requirements. Maybe you would want to look into "Hexagonal architecture" http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture